# How do I loop an elif statement back to input and change the printout?

Tags: python

I am very new to this, it is not part of my work but I have to take a scripting class for me degree.  The final is to make a game (I won't go into details since I only need help on this section for now).  So, I have my starting code set up but I want to loop two of the statements back to the input so if the user input is 'investigate' or any other command not defined, it loops back to the input for another take.  If the input is the same thing again, I want to loop back again but with a different print.  This is what I have so far and yes I know it's not the best, I'm still working on it slowly...

Oh, the lines I want to loop are the elif and else statements too.  Thank you ahead of time for any advice ^.^

```
print("You awaken in a room in an unfamiliar cabin.  As you make your way to your feet you see outside the window is a mass of black tentacles \n and a voice echoes from below the house.  'Hah, mortal! Thou art no match for the powers of the abyss.  Thou shalt feel the depths of misery and despair' ")
print()
print("After this a soft whisper graces your ear and a different voice, one soft like a child's whispers 'Valiant hero, save us and we shall lend you \n  our power to vanquish the horror below' ")
print()
print("And so your journey begins.  Make haste and rescue the elements in order to save yourself.  Good luck!")
print()
print("You are currently on the main floor.  Please enter a direction you would like to go.  You can enter north, south, east, or west to go in the \n desired direction.  You may also investigate rooms with the investigate command")


user_input = input()

directions = ['north', 'east', 'south', 'west']
investigate = ['investigate']

if user_input == directions[0]:
    print("You have ascended the staircase to the second floor.  You stand in a bedroom with a door leading to the balcony to your side and the \n staircase behind you.  Beside the bed the lamp on the table seems dim... \n Please enter your direction or investigate.")
elif user_input == directions[3]:
    print("You have entered the bathroom.  The sound of water dripping seems to echo throughout the room as if it were the only sound being made. \n Please enter a direction or investigate")
elif user_input == directions[2]:
    print("You Find your way down the stairs leading you to the cellar below.  The scent of earth all around you.  To the East you can hear chanting in an inhumane \n voice that sends a shiver up your spine.  \n Please chose a direction or investigate.")
elif user_input == directions[1]:
    print("You find yourself in the kitchen.  The room seems much warmer than the others and the stove appears to be on.  To the north is a door leading \n to the pantry.  \n Please enter a direction or investigate")
elif user_input == investigate[0]:
    print("You look around the room and hear the withering of the tendrils sliding closer to the cabin... \n Please input a direction or investigate before it's too late!")
else:
    print("You look around in confusion at an unrecognized command.  Please enter a direction or investigate.")
```

Comment: Put everything in a `while` loop. Break out of the loop when you don't want to repeat.

Comment: Apart from the loop you most like will need a variable keeping current "state" of the game. Depending on the answers and current state your code will select new state.

Comment: Roman, that's the next part of the project I'm struggling with as well.  As I said, this is not the norm of a class for me nor is it my area of expertise, I'm an environmental specialist not a programer lol.  Kind of a McCoy "I'm a doctor not a bricklayer" moment for me...

Answer (score 0):

If you are on python 3.10 and up you can try this:

```
while True:
    match input('u, d, l, r, e: '):
        case 'u':
            print('up')
        case 'd':
            print('down')
        case 'l':
            print('left')
        case 'r':
            print('right')
        case 'e':
            print('Exit')
            exit(0)
        case other:
            print("don't know")
```

Of course adjust the code for your taste ...